# Counting folder size and showing at the same time (Multi Threading Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

I need to create a code that will count the size of some folder in system and show on JLabel the progress(in kilobytes). The counting part is done. I need the second part. It should be done with multithreading(changing the label text every 100 Millies). Thank you in advance. Here is the counting code.

```
public static long getFileSize(File folder) {

    long foldersize = 0;

    File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {

        if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) {

            foldersize += getFileSize(filelist[i]);

        } else {

            foldersize += filelist[i].length();

        }

    }

    return foldersize;
}
```

Comment: Let me google for you:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#bars,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ProgressBarDemoProject/src/components/ProgressBarDemo.java

Comment: Well, where is the JLabel you want to use? What have you tried so far? Do you expect us to write your code?

Comment: thank you , i found the solution myself, anf post it in answer, maybe someone will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Spawn a separate thread to call your getFolderSize function, and make `foldersize` a static volatile variable.  Then  you can access `foldersize` from your UI thread and use it to update the JLabel  periodically using `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i reached myself. The code above is creating simple UI. Button is counting the size of the given path and is printing the size of the given folder and the number of files and folders in the given path.

1. FolderSizeCounter.java

public class FileSizeCounter {

```
public static long getFileSize(File folder){


    long foldersize = 0;
    File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
    if(filelist!=null){
        for (int i=0; i < filelist.length; i++) {

            if(!filelist[i].isDirectory() && !filelist[i].isFile()){

                UI.nonfilecount++;
            }
            if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) {

                foldersize += getFileSize(filelist[i]);
                UI.foldercount++;

            } else {
                foldersize += filelist[i].length();
                UI.size+=filelist[i].length();
                UI.filecount++;
            }

        }

    }

    return foldersize;
}

public static String getReadableSizeByte(long size) {
    if(size <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size)/Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size/Math.pow(1024, digitGroups))
            + " " + units[digitGroups];
}

public static String getReadableSizeK(long size) {
    if(size <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] { " ","K", "M", "B", "T"};
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size)/Math.log10(1000));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size/Math.pow(1000, digitGroups))
            + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

}

2. UI.java

public class UI implements ActionListener {

```
private JFrame fr;
private JPanel pn;
static JLabel folderSize, info, folderCountlbl, fileCountlbl;
private JTextField tf;
private JButton but;
public static long size, foldercount, filecount, nonfilecount;
public int i = 0;

public UI() {

    fr = new JFrame();

    pn = new JPanel();

    info = new JLabel("Type the folder path !!!");
    folderSize = new JLabel();
    folderCountlbl = new JLabel();
    fileCountlbl = new JLabel();

    tf = new JTextField(12);

    but = new JButton("Count the size !!!");

    pn.add(info);
    pn.add(tf);
    pn.add(but);
    pn.add(folderSize);
    pn.add(folderCountlbl);
    pn.add(fileCountlbl);

    but.addActionListener(this);

    fr.add(pn);

    fr.setSize(220, 180);
    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    fr.setResizable(false);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == but) {
        if (new File(tf.getText()).isDirectory()) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    System.out.println(FileSizeCounter
                            .getReadableSizeByte(FileSizeCounter.getFileSize(new File(tf.getText()))));

                }
            });

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (t.isAlive()) {

                        folderSize.setText("Size of the folder " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeByte((size)));
                        folderCountlbl
                                .setText("Number of folders " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeK(foldercount));
                        fileCountlbl.setText("Number of files " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeK(filecount));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    folderSize.setText("Size of the folder " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeByte((size)));
                    folderCountlbl.setText("Number of folders " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeK(foldercount));
                    fileCountlbl.setText("Number of files " + FileSizeCounter.getReadableSizeK(filecount));
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            t.start();
        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fr, "Wrong path. Try again.", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);

        }

    }
}
```

}

3. and Main.java

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    new UI();
}
```

}